# Is an affine scheme compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

This is probably a very stupid question, because it is very well known that the spectrum of a ring is compact (quasi-compact, if you want). But an affine scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, if I am right, is just isomorphic, as a ringed space, to $(\operatorname{Spec}(A),\tilde{A})$ where $\tilde{A}$ is the canonical sheaf over $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. So, the definition doesn't (to my understanding) imply that the topological space $X$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$.

Comment: It does! An isomorphism of ringed spaces is in particular a homeomorphism on the underlying topological spaces.

Comment: Yes, because the underlying map of topological spaces of a map of schemes has to be continuous. There is in other words a forgetful functor $\text{Sch} \rightarrow \text{Top}$. And functors take isomorphic objects to isomorphic objects.

Comment: @hunter, I'm sorry for having been so confusingly brief. The point that I, very stupidly, am missing is that from the definition I'm working with, the isomorphism of ringed spaces is just a pair $(f,\Theta)$ where $f$ is a continuous function between $X$ and $Spec(A)$ and $\Theta$ is an isomorphism between the sheafs $\tilde{A}$ and $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, which, in principle, seems just to imply isomorphisms between $\tilde{A}(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))$ for every open set of $Spec(A)$. And the definition I gave at the beginning doesn't need $f$ to be an homeomorphism.

Comment: I think the statement is true but a little tricky to prove. The goal is to show that the map on structure sheaves determines the map on points, try working locally in the affine case. It's a good exercise I think!

Comment: @RobertoBenito That definition of isomorphism is wrong. For example, $\mathbb{P}^1_k \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ satisfies that definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin you are right. And my definition was wrong. It must be imposed the continuous function $f$ to be a homeomorphism. Thank you!